# Can I say "from now on, contact me"?

Tags: expressions

I'm writing a formal e-mail in order to inform our client that I took the place of a colleague...is this expression correct "I would like to inform you that X is no longer working at our company, so I’ll cover his responsibilities about this event"?
And then I will add something like "from now on, please contact me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can say both of these -- but I would suggest "responsibility/responsibilities **for**" instead of "*about*".

> - I would like to inform you that X is no longer working at our company, 
>     so I’ll cover his responsibilities **for** this event"
> - From now on, please contact me.

You can also say:

> - .. and I have **taken over his responsibilities for this event**.
> - .. and I have **taken over responsibility for his projects**.
> - .. and I **will have responsibility for this project.**